# Double Name and Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar, personal-name

I know similar questions have been asked before, though any links to contact Google Scholar that were provided in older answers no longer work.

I have two last names, example: First name Jane, Last name "Doe Smith". The google scholar algorithm chooses only the second part of my name as my "last name", even when the journal has published my work as Doe Smith, Jane. Instead Google Scholar will present it as JD Smith.

Is there anything I can do? Any way to contact Google Scholar, or fix it myself? I'm assuming the answer is to just live with it. I thought about just publishing under Jane Doe or Jane Smith from now on, but I've already published a lot under my name, and realistically, if I were to pick one I'd want it to be Doe, which may confuse the system that always wants to pick Smith.

Comment: It does answer part of it. But how about a way to contact Google Scholar. Or is that just impossible?

Comment: Looking at several other related questions on this site, it is highly unlikely that contacting google regarding any of their free services will be of any use.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete fix, but you *can* edit how your name and articles appear in *your* Scholar profile. Starting from your main Scholar page, you click on the article, and then there is a pop-up box; in the top right corner there is a pencil icon which will allow you to edit the list of authors.

However, I don't think this actually changes Scholar's underlying database. I keep hoping the algorithm will figure it out at some point :)

Comment: Yes I've done this! It doesn't totally fix the citation, and then it adds an asterisk next to the citation. I guess this may be the only choice for now =/

Comment: Actually - it only adds an asterisk if it thinks I'm changing the ordering of the names. Unfortunately, like you said, the change doesn't transfer to anywhere else in the system, only my google profile.Thank you!